# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_debugtoolbar'

Tags: python, docker, flask

I've got a basic Flask app running on Docker.
Running docker-compose up --build finishes with no errors; everything in the requirements.txt appears to have downloaded.

Running

```
    $ py.test flowstate/tests
```

gives a traceback of:

```
    ImportError while loading conftest '/Users/Jaime/python/flask/flowstate-api/flowstate/tests/conftest.py'.
    flowstate/tests/conftest.py:3: in
    from flowstate.app import create_app
    flowstate/app.py:5: in
    from flowstate.extensions import (
    flowstate/extensions.py:1: in
    from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
```

E ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_debugtoolbar'

Here are all the relevant files:

- app.py

```
    from flask import Flask
    
    from flowstate.blueprints.page import page
    
    from flowstate.extensions import (
        debug_toolbar,
        db,
        jwt,
        marshmallow
    )
    
    
    def create_app(settings_override=None):
        """ Create a Flask app using the factory pattern. """
    
        app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    
        app.config.from_object('config.settings')
        app.config.from_pyfile('settings.py', silent=True)
    
        if settings_override:
            app.config.update(settings_override)
    
        app.register_blueprint(page)
        
        extensions(app)
    
        return app
    
    
    def extensions(app):
        """ Mutate the app passed in. """
        debug_toolbar.init_app(app)
        jwt.init_app(app)
        db.init_app(app)
        marshmallow.init_app(app)
    
        return None
```

- extensions.py

```
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

debug_toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension()
jwt = JWTManager()
db = SQLAlchemy()
marshmallow = Marshmallow()
```

- requirements.txt

```
    # Python web app microframework 
    Flask==0.12
    
    # Flask dependencies
    itsdangerous==1.1.0
    markupsafe==1.1.1
    
    # WSGI HTTP server
    gunicorn==19.4
    
    # WSGI app library
    werkzeug==0.15.5
    
    # HTML templating library for Flask
    jinja2==2.11.3
    
    # Relational databases w/ Python
    SQLAlchemy==1.2.0
    SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.32
    
    # Integrate relational databases into app
    Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
    
    # PostgreSQL database adapter in C
    psycopg2==2.8.3
    
    # API / JWT Auth
    flask-classful==0.14
    flask-marshmallow==0.14.0
    marshmallow==3.0.0
    marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.27.0
    flask-jwt-extended==3.3
    PyJWT==1.7.1
    
    # Testing
    pytest==2.9
    
    # CLI command handling
    Click==6.4
    
    # Extensions
    flask-debugtoolbar==0.13.1
    faker==0.8.7
    
    # Environmental variables
    python-dotenv==0.20.0
```

I have tried upgrading to the newest version of debug_toolbar, still with the same results.
I also have the nagging feeling that this affects the rest of my extensions as well.
Such a simple traceback, so much heartbreak. Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: what is the command that you run and results in that error? You say it runs in Docker but in your error there is a reference to a path that looks to be on your host and that's very strange.

Comment: first: $ docker-compose up --build, then $ py.test flowstate/tests

Comment: so you start the containers but then you launch `py.test ....` on the host. Is that right? You are not connecting to a container in order to run the command inside.